# Sorting MYSQL returns into arrays for printing causes array to be repeated unnecessarily

Tags: php, arrays, loops, sorting

I have a project where I'm transcribing data from historical sources, which is then saved into a MYSQL database, and is then displayed in an HTML page, using PHP to do all the work for arranging things for display.

The problem I'm facing right now is that the code I'm using for sorting the data into arrays for display is causing the output lines to be duplicated so that the data is displayed twice, one after another.

here is the data going into the function (which I've grabbed from a var_export[edited])

So here is the results of the var_export for $lines, which is the lines passed into the function.
There are 8 lines here, which is correct (Test Ships A through H)
A-C are assigned to column 1
D-F are assigned to column 2
G & H are assigned to column 3

here is the var_export for section_flags
array ( 0 => (object) array( 'report_section_key' => 'dsk_61ee0a39380dd', 'report_key' => 'sdr61ee09e0cea3a', 'section_number' => '1', 'ship_name_label' => 'Shipps', 'ship_label_position' => '0', 'captain_label' => 'Captains', 'captain_column_position' => '1', 'lieutenants_label' => 'N/A', 'lieutenants_used' => '-1', 'men_used' => '2', 'men_label' => 'Crew', 'guns_used' => '-1', 'guns_label' => 'N/A', 'rate_used' => '-1', 'rate_label' => 'N/A', 'location_0_used' => '-1', 'location_0_label' => 'N/A', 'location_0_field' => 'not_used', 'location_1_used' => '-1', 'location_1_label' => 'N/A', 'location_1_field' => 'not_used', 'date_cleaned_used' => '-1', 'date_cleaned_label' => 'N/A', 'date_wages_start_label' => 'N/A', 'date_wages_start_position' => '-1', 'time_in_pay_used_months' => '-1', 'time_in_pay_label_months' => 'N/A', 'how_many_columns' => '3', 'section_comment' => '', 'start_with_subtitle' => '0', 'time_in_pay_used_weeks' => '-1', 'time_in_pay_label_weeks' => 'N/A', ), )

array ( 0 => (object) array( 'ship_name_as_written' => 'Test Ship A', 'captain_name_as_written' => 'Test Captain A', 'crew' => '1', 'archival_reference' => 'Just a test Reference', 'comment' => 'None Listed', 'section_column_number' => '1', 'line_number' => '0', ), 1 => (object) array( 'ship_name_as_written' => 'Test Ship B', 'captain_name_as_written' => 'Captain B', 'crew' => '2', 'archival_reference' => 'Just a test Reference', 'comment' => 'None Listed', 'section_column_number' => '1', 'line_number' => '1', ), 2 => (object) array( 'ship_name_as_written' => 'Test Ship C', 'captain_name_as_written' => 'Test Captain C', 'crew' => '3', 'archival_reference' => 'Just a test Reference', 'comment' => 'None Listed', 'section_column_number' => '1', 'line_number' => '2', ), 3 => (object) array( 'ship_name_as_written' => 'Test Ship D', 'captain_name_as_written' => 'Test Captain D', 'crew' => '4', 'archival_reference' => 'Just a test Reference', 'comment' => 'None Listed', 'section_column_number' => '2', 'line_number' => '3', ), 4 => (object) array( 'ship_name_as_written' => 'Test Ship E', 'captain_name_as_written' => 'Test Captain E', 'crew' => '5', 'archival_reference' => 'Just a test Reference', 'comment' => 'None Listed', 'section_column_number' => '2', 'line_number' => '4', ), 5 => (object) array( 'ship_name_as_written' => 'Test Ship F', 'captain_name_as_written' => 'Test Captain F', 'crew' => '6', 'archival_reference' => 'Just a test Reference', 'comment' => 'None Listed', 'section_column_number' => '2', 'line_number' => '5', ), 6 => (object) array( 'ship_name_as_written' => 'Test Ship G', 'captain_name_as_written' => 'Test Captain G', 'crew' => '7', 'archival_reference' => 'Just a test Reference', 'comment' => 'None Listed', 'section_column_number' => '3', 'line_number' => '6', ), 7 => (object) array( 'ship_name_as_written' => 'Test Ship H', 'captain_name_as_written' => 'Test Captain H', 'crew' => '8', 'archival_reference' => 'Just a test Reference', 'comment' => 'None Listed', 'section_column_number' => '3', 'line_number' => '7', ), )

here is the var_export for Subs
rray ( 0 => (object) array( 'summary_abstract_key' => 'sub_ab61ee1f5f85a31', 'report_key' => 'sdr61ee09e0cea3a', 'section_key' => 'dsk_61ee0a39380dd', 'line_number' => '8', 'field_text' => 'Third Column Group Subtitle', 'column_number' => '3', ), )

*****Here is the output of the sorting function - including the subtitles. (This actually is a var-dump of each part of the output array). I'm confused as hell because as I expected these sub arrays to have numberic keys, which are the column number (and they don't seem to), and  because the last group is doubled- and I don't understand how that happens in the code.

array(3) { [3]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(11) "Test Ship D" [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXBDx.png)=> string(14) "Test Captain D" [2]=> string(1) "4" [30]=> string(21) "Just a test Reference" [31]=> string(11) "None Listed" } [4]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(11) "Test Ship E" [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXBDx.png)=> string(14) "Test Captain E" [2]=> string(1) "5" [30]=> string(21) "Just a test Reference" [31]=> string(11) "None Listed" } [5]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(11) "Test Ship F" [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXBDx.png)=> string(14) "Test Captain F" [2]=> string(1) "6" [30]=> string(21) "Just a test Reference" [31]=> string(11) "None Listed" } }

array(3) { [6]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(11) "Test Ship G" [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXBDx.png)=> string(14) "Test Captain G" [2]=> string(1) "7" [30]=> string(21) "Just a test Reference" [31]=> string(11) "None Listed" } [7]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(11) "Test Ship H" [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXBDx.png)=> string(14) "Test Captain H" [2]=> string(1) "8" [30]=> string(21) "Just a test Reference" [31]=> string(11) "None Listed" } [8]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(27) "Third Column Group Subtitle" } }

array(3) { [6]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(11) "Test Ship G" [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXBDx.png)=> string(14) "Test Captain G" [2]=> string(1) "7" [30]=> string(21) "Just a test Reference" [31]=> string(11) "None Listed" } [7]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(11) "Test Ship H" [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXBDx.png)=> string(14) "Test Captain H" [2]=> string(1) "8" [30]=> string(21) "Just a test Reference" [31]=> string(11) "None Listed" } [8]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(27) "Third Column Group Subtitle" } } lines

array(3) { [3]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(11) "Test Ship A" [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXBDx.png)=> string(14) "Test Captain A" [2]=> string(1) "1" [30]=> string(21) "Just a test Reference" [31]=> string(11) "None Listed" } [4]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(11) "Test Ship B" [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXBDx.png)=> string(14) "Test Captain B" [2]=> string(1) "2" [30]=> string(21) "Just a test Reference" [31]=> string(11) "None Listed" } [5]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(11) "Test Ship C" [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXBDx.png)=> string(14) "Test Captain C" [2]=> string(1) "3" [30]=> string(21) "Just a test Reference" [31]=> string(11) "None Listed" } }

as you can see, the "last" group here is duplicated- what's getting me, is I don't understand why it's only the "last" group to be duplicated- if I have group of lines, it gets duplicated, if I have two, it's only the "more recent".

here is the actual code

```
function newest_sort_ship_deployment_line_single_section($section_flags, $lines,$subs)
{
//var_dump ($section_flags);
//var_dump ($lines);
    
$section_sorted = array();
foreach ($lines as $line)
{ // use the line numeber
    
    //echo  "column number " . $line->section_column_number . "<br>";
    
    echo "the line in question <br>";  //HAVE TO PUT THE SECTION FLAGS SHIT BACK B/C it's needed. Tomorrow
    var_dump ($line);
    echo "<br>";      
    //$section_sorted[$line->section_column_number] = array();      
    $section_sorted[$line->section_column_number] [$line->line_number] = array();
    if ($section_flags[0]->ship_label_position != -1)
    {
        if ($line->ship_name_as_written == "None Listed")
        {
            $section_sorted[$line->section_column_number] [$line->line_number][$section_flags[0]->ship_label_position] = " "; //now, copy this
        }
        elseif ($line->ship_name_as_written == "N/A")
        {
            //shouldn't happen
            $section_sorted [$line->section_column_number] [$line->line_number][$section_flags[0]->ship_label_position] = "Not Used- Error";
        }
        else
        {
            $section_sorted [$line->section_column_number] [$line->line_number][$section_flags[0]->ship_label_position] = $line->ship_name_as_written;
        }   
    }

    if ($section_flags[0]->captain_column_position != -1)
    {
        if ($line->captain_name_as_written == "None Listed")
        {
            $section_sorted [$line->section_column_number] [$line->line_number][$section_flags[0]->captain_column_position] = " ";
        }
        elseif ($line->captain_name_as_written == "N/A")
        {
            //shouldn't happen
            $section_sorted [$line->section_column_number] [$line->line_number][$section_flags[0]->captain_column_position] = "Not Used- Error";
        }
        else
        {
            $section_sorted [$line->section_column_number] [$line->line_number][$section_flags[0]->captain_column_position] = $line->captain_name_as_written;
        }   
    }

    if ($section_flags[0]->lieutenants_used != -1)
    {       
        if ($line->lieutenants_as_written == "None Listed")
        {
            $section_sorted [$line->section_column_number] [$line->line_number][$section_flags[0]->lieutenants_used] = " ";
        }
        elseif ($line->lieutenants_as_written == "N/A")
        {
            //shouldn't happen
            $section_sorted [$line->section_column_number] [$line->line_number][$section_flags[0]->lieutenants_used] = "Not Used- Error";
        }
        else
        {
            $section_sorted [$line->section_column_number] [$line->line_number][$section_flags[0]->lieutenants_used] = $line->lieutenants_as_written;
        }   
    }

    if ($section_flags[0]->men_used != -1)
    {
        if ($line->crew == "0")
        {
            $section_sorted [$line->section_column_number] [$line->line_number][$section_flags[0]->men_used] = " ";
        }
        elseif ($line->crew == "-1")
        {
            //shouldn't happen
            $section_sorted [$line->section_column_number] [$line->line_number][$section_flags[0]->men_used] = "Not Used- Error";
        }
        else
        {
            $section_sorted [$line->section_column_number] [$line->line_number][$section_flags[0]->men_used] = $line->crew;
        }
    }

    if ($section_flags[0]->guns_used != -1) 
    {
        if ($line->ship_guns == "0")
        {
            $section_sorted [$line->section_column_number] [$line->line_number][$section_flags[0]->guns_used] = " ";
        }
        elseif ($line->ship_guns == "-1")
        {
            //shouldn't happen
            $section_sorted [$line->section_column_number] [$line->line_number][$section_flags[0]->guns_used] = "Not Used- Error";
        }
        else
        {
            $section_sorted [$line->section_column_number] [$line->line_number][$section_flags[0]->guns_used] = $line->ship_guns;
        }
    }

    if ($section_flags[0]->rate_used != -1)
    {
        if ($line->ship_rate == "0")
        {
            $section_sorted [$line->section_column_number] [$line->line_number][$section_flags[0]->rate_used] = " ";
        }
        elseif ($line->ship_rate == "-1")
        {
            //shouldn't happen
            $section_sorted [$line->section_column_number] [$line->line_number][$section_flags[0]->rate_used] = "Not Used- Error";
        }
        else
        {
            $section_sorted [$line->section_column_number] [$line->line_number][$section_flags[0]->rate_used] = $line->ship_rate;
        }
    }
    
    $fieldtext0 = $section_flags[0]->location_0_field;
    $fieldtext1 = $section_flags[0]->location_1_field;

    if ($section_flags[0]->location_0_used != -1)
    {   //field name is in section flags
        if ($line->$fieldtext0 == "None Listed")
        {
            $section_sorted [$line->section_column_number] [$line->line_number][$section_flags[0]->location_0_used] = " ";
        }
        elseif ($line->$fieldtext0  == "N/A")
        {
            //shouldn't happen
            $section_sorted [$line->section_column_number] [$line->line_number][$section_flags[0]->location_0_used] = "Not Used- Error";
        }
        else
        {
            $section_sorted [$line->section_column_number] [$line->line_number][$section_flags[0]->location_0_used] = $line->$fieldtext0;
        }
    }   

    if ($section_flags[0]->location_1_used != -1)
    {
        //field name is in section flags
        if ($line->$fieldtext1 == "None Listed")
        {
            $section_sorted [$line->section_column_number] [$line->line_number][$section_flags[0]->location_1_used] = " ";
        }
        elseif ($line->$fieldtext1  == "N/A")
        {
            //shouldn't happen
            $section_sorted [$line->section_column_number] [$line->line_number][$section_flags[0]->location_1_used] = "Not Used- Error";
        }
        else
        {
            $section_sorted [$line->section_column_number] [$line->line_number][$section_flags[0]->location_1_used] = $line->$fieldtext1;
        }
    }

    if ($section_flags[0]->date_wages_start_position != -1)
    {   
        if ($line->date_wages_start == "1000-01-01")
        {
            $section_sorted [$line->section_column_number] [$line->line_number][$section_flags[0]-> date_wages_start_position] = " ";
        }
        elseif ($line->date_wages_start == "0001-01-01")
        {
            //shouldn't happen
            $section_sorted [$line->section_column_number] [$line->line_number][$section_flags[0]-> date_wages_start_position] = "Not Used- Error";
        }
        else
        {
            $section_sorted [$line->section_column_number] [$line->line_number][$section_flags[0]-> date_wages_start_position] = $line->date_wages_start;
        }
    }

    if ($section_flags[0]->date_cleaned_used  != -1)
    {   
        if ($line->date_cleaned == "1000-01-01")
        {
            $section_sorted [$line->section_column_number] [$line->line_number][$section_flags[0]->date_cleaned_used] = " ";
        }
        elseif ($line->date_cleaned == "0001-01-01")
        {
            //shouldn't happen
            $section_sorted [$line->section_column_number] [$line->line_number][$section_flags[0]->date_cleaned_used] = "Not Used- Error";
        }
        else
        {
            $section_sorted [$line->section_column_number] [$line->line_number][$section_flags[0]->date_cleaned_used] = $line->date_cleaned;
        }
    }

    if ($section_flags[0]->time_in_pay_used_months != -1)
    {
        if ($line->time_sea_pay_months == "0")
        {
            $section_sorted [$line->section_column_number] [$line->line_number][$section_flags[0]->time_in_pay_used_months] = " ";
        }
        elseif ($line->time_sea_pay_months == "-1")
        {
            //shouldn't happen
            $section_sorted [$line->section_column_number] [$line->line_number][$section_flags[0]->time_in_pay_used_months] = "Not Used- Error";
        }
        else
        {
            $section_sorted [$line->section_column_number] [$line->line_number][$section_flags[0]->time_in_pay_used_months] = $line->time_sea_pay_months;
        }
    }

    if ($section_flags[0]->time_in_pay_used_weeks != -1)
    {
        if ($line->time_sea_pay_weeks == "0")
        {
            $section_sorted [$line->section_column_number] [$line->line_number][$section_flags[0]->time_in_pay_used_weeks] = " ";
        }
        elseif ($line->time_sea_pay_weeks == "-1")
        {
            //shouldn't happen
            $section_sorted [$line->section_column_number] [$line->line_number][$section_flags[0]->time_in_pay_used_weeks] = "Not Used- Error";
        }
        else
        {
            $section_sorted [$line->section_column_number] [$line->line_number][$section_flags[0]->time_in_pay_used_weeks] = $line-> time_sea_pay_weeks;
        }
    }     
    
    $thing_to_sort = $section_sorted [$line->section_column_number][$line->line_number];
    ksort ($thing_to_sort, SORT_NUMERIC);
    $section_sorted [$line->section_column_number][$line->line_number] = $thing_to_sort;
    
    $section_sorted [$line->section_column_number][$line->line_number][30]  = $line->archival_reference;
    if ($line->line_comment == NULL)
    {
        $section_sorted [$line->section_column_number][$line->line_number][31]  = "None Listed";
    }
    else
    {
        $section_sorted [$line->section_column_number][$line->line_number][31]  = $line->line_comment;  
    }
    
    
}

    //now, add the subtitles
    foreach ($subs as $sub)
    {
        $section_sorted [$sub->column_number] [$sub->line_number][0] = $sub->field_text;
    }

/*echo "Section sorted<br>";
var_dump ($section_sorted);
echo "SS over <br>";*/

$thing_to_sort = array();
$thing_counter = 0;

//NEED TO SORT OUT THE SORTING TO GET SUBTITLES IN THE RIGHT PLACE
foreach ($section_sorted as $column)
{
    $thing_to_sort = $column;
    ksort ($thing_to_sort, SORT_NUMERIC);
    $section_sorted[$thing_counter] = $thing_to_sort;
    $thing_counter++;
}

//sort columns by line number to get them right


/*echo "section sorted <br>";
var_dump ($section_sorted);
echo "<br>";*/

return $section_sorted;
}
```

[image]

here a visual example of how the data is output (after being passed through another function that does the layout). Clearly, there's another issue here because the actual columns aren't in order either (I need another sort to get them in order), but you can see that G and H are repeated on the right, when they should not be.

Anyways, I'm completely at a loss to understand how more arrays are being created than column-groups and if anybody can help me spot the issue, I would very much appreciate it.

New Twist: I went and changed the "column_number" values for the lines above from 1-3 to 0-2 and things started displaying normally/perfect. So there's something in my code that objects to the array of data (that gets fed to the display function) starting with element 1 instead of element 0, and the largest number element is also used as element 0. That is really weird.

So while I've "solved" the problem in that I now have things displaying properly, I still need to solve why the code I've written does that so I can stop that behaviour.

Comment: Not looked at the code yet, but why dont you do all the sorting and grouping in mysql?

Comment: @Grumpy Honestly, b/c I'm not sure how to do it in MYSQL. Also, I don't run the web server, and I've found that with more complicated queries the connection times out so it's more reliable to just do the data pull and do all the sorting in PHP.

Comment: Please don't take this the wrong way, but all of those nested `if` statements along with deeply nested arrays are screaming  "potential problems". I'm not saying they are wrong or bad, just that it is very complex code that is hard to reason about. To your problem, can you post sample data that we can actually input and test against, along with the expected output. What you have posted above would need to be hand re-written for us to use. Also, is everything above "NEED TO SORT" actually germane to the problem, and if not, can it just be ignored by us to focus on the sort?

Comment: @ChrisHaas It is all germane, the problem is that I am expecting the array to be passed out containing
[1] containing 3 items
[2] containing 3 items
[3] containing 3 items

but I'm also getting [0] or [4] containing 3 items- replicating [3].

And I just don't understand how or why this is happening given that there are only 3 values for [column_number]. Somehow, running through each line, if the line has the largest [column_number] value, two arrays are created, not 1, and I don't get it.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the `var_dump` you've posted just isn't useful because the data is too complex to spot, at least with my eyes. I need actual data that I can copy and paste into PHP to test with.

Comment: @ChrisHaas what's the best way to do that? I could write simply complex Array statement in PHP, but I'm not sure that's the best

Comment: The best way is generally to simplify. You have a very complex function. If you remove the block `if ($section_flags[0]->ship_label_position != -1)` your output will obviously not be ideal, but is your problem (or a version of it) still there? If the problem is still there, that specific chunk isn't related to the problem and we don't need to know about it. Repeat. Almost every one of those `if` blocks seems to do very similar work, and I can't imagine that they are all causing the duplication or grouping problem. If they aren't, that also means the source data can be simplified, too.

Comment: The changes are for debugging purposes only, so that either you can spot the problem, or you can communicate with us using as little code as possible. Once the problem is resolved, these can be added back one-by-one.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Chris, the problem seems to be in this block

Comment: If this were my code, I personally would break things up into smaller chunks that are easier to reason about, and that avoid duplication of code. I also very like returning early in functions because I can avoid `else` statements, and alias deeply nested arrays. If I were to work on code like this, the first thing I would do would be to turn each of those `if` blocks into [dedicated functions](https://3v4l.org/6iJUX). I'm not saying your code is wrong, it just becomes easier to think about

Comment: @ChrisHaas Chris, the problem seems to be in this block

foreach ($section_sorted as $column)
 {
  $thing_to_sort = $column;
  ksort ($thing_to_sort, SORT_NUMERIC);
  $section_sorted[$thing_counter] = $thing_to_sort;
  $thing_counter++;
 }

I'm not sure *how* it's the issue. If I comment it out, what happens is that 

Group 3 is printed first, then there's 3 empty space, then Group 1, then Group 2.

so something is wrong with that sort, and I can't figure it out

Comment: You need to come up with a way to give us source data. It doesn't have to be real but it must be representative. That burden is on you. A `var_dump` cannot be brought back into PHP, although a `var_export` can be. Make a version of your code that includes source data and works on https://3v4l.org/. As a hint, you might have multiple lines but we probably don't need them all. Per your last comment, maybe we only need the data at the point forward. Regardless, with that much code and complexity we need something that works independent of computer that it is run on. That's the last I'll say on it

Comment: @ChrisHaas breaking it down into smaller functions is a thing to consider, except that- I wouldn't use those dedicated functions in more than one place, they'd just be called by this larger function.

Comment: @ChrisHaas I didn't know about the var_export function! Thanks for telling me about that. 

Ask and Ye Shall Receive. I'll put into the post if i can fit it

Comment: Okay, one last thing. Breaking code into multiple functions isn't solely about code reuse. It is also about "this does a thing given a set of inputs and I don't need to think about it anymore". If you look at my sample, the only inputs are `$line`. So those functions do just a single thing, they are very obvious, and they have no care in the world about `$section_flags` or anything else. They also make your main function much smaller and easier to read.